# error from function CGDataProviderCopyData : JPEGDecompressSurface : Picture decode failed: e00002c2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have error "JPEGDecompressSurface : Picture decode failed: e00002c2" in my console thrown from the function CGDataProviderCopyData, when I try to get pixels from GCImage. Despite this, everything works as expected, but I would like to get rid of this error and understand what could be wrong. 
I don't how to get to the bottom what is wrong. Will be grateful for any ideas.

The code:

```
NSData* nsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer length:inBufferSize];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: nsData]; // looks good in debugger
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGDataProviderRef refData = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
CFDataRef pixels = CGDataProviderCopyData(refData); // error appears in the console
```

Thanks!